# Python - Why win32clipboard is unable to paste to Google unless pasting to GUI first

Tags: python, copy, paste, pysimplegui

Part of a project I'm working on requires I copy a generated "password" variable to the clipboard.
I'm using PySimpleGUI and when the password is generated, I click a "Copy" button and it should save the password to the clipboard, however, trying to paste this to an external program (Google Chrome for example), nothing happens, but if I press Ctrl+V in a box on the PySimpleGUI interface, the password appears and I can then paste it to an external program (Google Chrome).

```
    if event == "Copy" and password is not None:
        win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
        win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
        win32clipboard.SetClipboardText(password)
```

Is there a way I can make it so the password can be pasted straight from clipboard to google without having to paste it inside the program first?

Answer (score 0):

One additional line of code needed for this to function properly.

```
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
```

I'm not sure why it would allow me to paste in google if I had first pasted it inside the GUI, so if anyone knows the answer then please say, but the line of code above will solve similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

There's no code provided by you for the GUI.

Following code work well.

```py
import win32clipboard
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Input(key='INPUT')],
    [sg.Button('COPY')],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'COPY':
        text = values['INPUT']
        if text:
            win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
            win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
            win32clipboard.SetClipboardText(text)
            win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

window.close()
```

Comment: There are clipboard operations built into PySimpleGUI, but can have some limitations if the PySimpleGUI window is closed (it's a tkinter-thing).  Depends on tkinter version, OS, etc.